# Turning SVG image into png for unsupported browsers - Fallback - modernizer.js(?)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, png, fallback

I'm looking at turning a few `SVG` images I have on my site in `PNG` for browsers that don't support `SVG` properly. I'm mostly having issues with the text based ones being shown in `IE` (completely wrong font being displayed), so I thought I'd create a fallback to `PNG`.

I've tried look for a nice walkthrough for this (I'm a self confessed noob) and I haven't managed to make it all work yet. I believe I want to use [modernizer.js](http://modernizr.com/) to check for compatibility, then serve in incompatible different images(?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chris Coyier answers this exact question in the latest [Smashing Magazine CSS Q&A](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/15/css-qa-4/).

1. Download a version of **Modernizr** that is trimmed down to just testing
   SVG (assuming that’s the only test you need).
2. Run the test. If it
   passes, put in the SVG. If it fails, put in the bitmap. Essentially:

Example (JS solution):

```js
if (!Modernizr.svg) {
    $("#logo").css("background-image", "url(fallback.png)");
}
```

Example (CSS solution):

```css
.no-svg #logo { background-image: url(fallback.png); }
```

This should only be necessary for IE8 and below. **Can I use** has a [full table of browser support](http://caniuse.com/svg).

Thanks Chris!

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that :) 
Thank you very much!