# css svg and vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" browser compatibility

Tags: css, svg

From various sources I gather that vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" in svg should work in the current versions Opera, Firefox and Chrome. (Not sure about IE10).

However I can only make it work in Opera and Firefox, and then only when it is directly embedded as an image, if it is scaled as a background image in CSS then it doesn't work.

My questions:

Why not chrome?

Why not in background images?

Is there a standard way I can use this in all latest browsers?

[A fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/79RKa/)

HTML :

```
<div><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60476509/close.svg" /></div>
<div><img id="one" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60476509/close.svg" /></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#one {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#two {
    background-image: url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60476509/close.svg");
    height: 100px;   /* native size */
    width: 100px;
    background-size: contain;        
}
#three {
    background-image: url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60476509/close.svg");
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: cover;        
}
```

Comment: Works in Chrome if you place the SVG inline: http://jsfiddle.net/42mq6/, not sure how to work around your problem though.

Comment: @Duopixel Thanks, that is an improvement, even if a hassle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what's going on under the hood, but there is an easier solution, at least for inline SVG's (not sure about backgrounds). Change:

```
<img src="svg-source.svg"/>
```

to:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="svg-source.svg"></object>
```

In addition, you need to make sure you have [`viewBox` defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335926/svg-viewbox-attribute) for the svg document.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482962/2472391), using `object` is better practice anyway. [Here](http://e.metaclarity.org/52/cross-browser-svg-issues/) is a decent blog post that recommends (for cross-browser compatibility):

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="svg-source.svg">
    <img src="png-version.png"/>
</object>
```

I have not tested this latter option, but if it works it is much simpler than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13059502/2472391) solution.

EDIT: I discovered that as embedded objects, SVGs were interfering with "hover" and "click" events, so I finally buckled and decided that I must embed SVGs fully. But I had no interest in pasting every single one, so I have the following at the top of my javascript file (I'm using JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.deferred-load').deferredLoad();
}
$.fn.deferredLoad = function()
{
    $(this).each(function()
    {
        $(this).load($(this).attr('data-load'));
    });
}
```

Now instead of `<img src="svg.svg"/>` I can write `<div class="deferred-load" data-load="svg.svg"></div>`.

Of course, this doesn't work without Javascript enabled. But it's way better than pasting all that ugly XML.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood UAs need to draw the SVG and then turn it into a bitmap to create an image (including a background image). The easiest way is to draw it is to reuse the non-image rendering code and then scale the bitmap but when the bitmap is scaled it becomes both blurred and also doesn't render non-scaling stroke properly. The right way is to figure out what size you eventually want to draw the bitmap at and tell the SVG drawing code to draw into that.

This [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600207) has just been fixed in Firefox. You can try in a [Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) today or wait for the release in September.